# pipe value to sed and use it in the replace string

Tags: bash, awk, sed, centos

I am trying to programmatically generate a user and password, then hash the password and store it in the grub config file

I currently have this

```
# add a superuser account and password for the bootloader
## generate a secure password
pw=$(openssl rand -base64 32)

## create the new user for the bootloader and set the password as the secure password
useradd grub2superuseraccount
echo $pw | passwd grub2superuseraccount --stdin

## store the password to a TEMP file (needed to pass the password to grub2_mkpassword-pbkdf command, it will be deleted after)
cat << END >> ~/pfile
$pw
$pw
END

## generate the password hash and store it in the bootloader config file
cat ~/pfile | grub2-mkpasswd-pbkdf2 | sed -i "/password_pbkdf2/a password_pbkdf2 $THEVALUEOFTHEOUTPUTFROMTHEPIPE"

## delete the file with the password
rm ~/pfile
```

How can I pass the hashed password output from 'grub2-mkpasswd-pbkdf2' to the sed command?

OR

If there is another way to do this more elegantly, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Probably you can use process substitution to achieve your target.

Comment: I am using this example that apparently allows it 

https://github.com/ryran/burg2-mkpasswd-pbkdf2/blob/master/README.md

Comment: If your script contains the variable in memory anyway, making the script write the password to a file doesn't really improve security.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a refactoring which also avoids the pesky temporary file.

```
pw=$(openssl rand -base64 32)
useradd grub2superuseraccount
# Notice proper quoting
echo "$pw" | passwd grub2superuseraccount --stdin
# Collect output into a variable
grubpw=$(printf '%s\n' "$pw" "$pw" | grub2-mkpasswd-pbkdf2)
# Use the variable in sed -i
sed -i "/password_pbkdf2/a password_pbkdf2 $grubpw" conffile
```

Your question doesn't indicate the name of `conffile` so obviously replace that with the name of the file you actually want to run `sed -i` on.

If the output from `grub2-mkpasswd-pdkdf2` could contain newlines or other problematic characters, maybe add some escaping to the variable.

If you really genuinely require a pipe to be used, maybe look into `xargs`.

```
printf '%s\n' "$pw" "$pw" |
grub2-mkpasswd-pbkdf2 |
xargs -i sed -i "/password_pbkdf2/a password_pbkdf2 {}" conffile
```

Comment: That looks a lot more elegant indeed, I will give this a try! Thanks for the quick replies to you all

Comment: I updated the question with your input if you are interested, thanks again!

Comment: Your question should remain strictly a question. If you want to add an answer of your own, you are welcome to do it. (You can retrieve your changes from the [revision history.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54665319/revisions))

Answer (score 2):

> How can I pass the hashed password output from 'grub2-mkpasswd-pbkdf2' to the sed command?

Via command substitution, no pipes needed:

```
sed -i "/password_pbkdf2/c password_pbkdf2 $(grub2-mkpasswd-pbkdf2 < ~/pfile)" your_grub.conf
```

Note that I changed your `sed` command slightly, using `c` to **c**hange the entire line to what follows the command, instead of `a` which **a**ppends an entirely new line.

Comment: @Inian Sorry, I meant _command_ substitution. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GNU/Bash `read` to reach your needs, for instance:

```
cat ~/pfile | grub2-mkpasswd-pbkdf2 | (read THEVALUEOFTHEOUTPUTFROMTHEPIPE && sed -i "/password_pbkdf2/a password_pbkdf2 $THEVALUEOFTHEOUTPUTFROMTHEPIPE")
```